# How to count the number of collisions between group objects in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame

If someone wants to write a conditional code statement in a pygame based game that would require detection of the number of collisions between two group objects specifically, which function would they use?? The pygame library does not have a prewritten function apparently for counting group collisions only, and whenever I try writing one, pygame crashes but no errors are found/returned by the IDLE.
Say I want two collisions to occur and count them before I execute the following block of code:

```
def _update_bullets(self):
        self.bullets.update()
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
               self.bullets.remove(bullet)
      
        final =pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.scarfys, False, True)
```

and whenever I write the following if statements below
`final = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.scarfys, False, True):`

```
for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            hitCount = 0
            while hitCount < 1:
                if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.scarfys, True, False):
                    hitCount += 1
            final = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.scarfys, True, True)
```

I run the program with no errors appearing in the IDLE, however when I press the key to shoot a bullet (which I've tested before to ensure that it works properly without the collision counting condition ) I get a "program is not responsive error from windows" but still no errors in the IDLE.
For reference here are the classes/ groups in question:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Scarfy(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,kns):
      super().__init__()
      self.screen = kns.screen
      self.settings =  kns.settings
      self.image = pygame.image.load('cutescarfy.bmp')
      self.shot = pygame.image.load('onehit.bmp')
      self.seq = pygame.image.load('transformation.bmp')
      self.real = pygame.image.load('realscarfy.bmp')
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.x = self.rect.width
      self.rect.y = self.rect.height
      self.x = float(self.rect.x)
      self.y = float(self.rect.y)
      self.scarfys = kns.scarfys
```

...

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,kns):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = kns.screen
        self.color = (255,229,184)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,kns.settings.bullet_width,kns.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop= kns.kirby.rect.midtop
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.x = float(kns.kirby.rect.x)
        self.bullet_speed = kns.settings.bullet_speed
        self.scarfys = kns.scarfys
    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def drawbullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.color,self.rect)
```

I also created group objects based off each class:

```
def _create_rows(self):
        scarfy = Scarfy(self) 
        scarfy_width = scarfy.rect.width
        avaliableSpaceHor = self.settings.screen_width - (2*scarfy_width)
        rowCapacity = (avaliableSpaceHor//(2*scarfy_width))-1
        scarfy_height = scarfy.rect.height
        avaliableSpaceVer = self.settings.screen_height - (8*scarfy_height)
        rowCount = avaliableSpaceVer//(2*scarfy_height)
        for rowNum in range(rowCount):
            for scarfyNum in range(rowCapacity):
                self._create_scarfy(scarfyNum,rowNum)
                  
    def _create_scarfy(self,scarfyNum,rowNum):
        scarfy = Scarfy(self) 
        scarfy_width = scarfy.rect.width
        scarfy_height = scarfy.rect.height 
        scarfy.x = scarfy_width + 2 * scarfy_width * scarfyNum
        scarfy.rect.x = scarfy.x
        scarfy.rect.y = scarfy.rect.height + 2 * scarfy.rect.height * rowNum
        self.scarfys.add(scarfy)
        

def _fire_bullet(self):
        bulletCount = len(self.bullets)
        if bulletCount <= self.settings.bullet_limit:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
```

I want two collisions to occur before I remove the individual collided rectangles/elements off screen

Comment: In groupcollide you pass `, False, True` as arguments which will kill your Scarfy immediately, but leave the Bullet to fly further. Is this what you want? Do you want the Bullet to be able to hit/kill two Scarfies?

Comment: `whenever I try writing one, pygame crashes but no errors are found/returned by the IDLE` sounds like your code is in an infinite loop; you should have learned to use a debugger by now which would easily let you figure that kind of stuff out. [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) is how to use PyCharm's free debugger.

Comment: I want to hit the enemy twice before deleting it

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you want to do is have an extra attribute `kills` in your Bullet class, initate it with 0 and manage it when iterating over the results of `groupcollide`. Something along the lines:

```
for bullet, scarfies in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.scarfys, False, True).items():
    if scarfies:
        # The bullet hit a scarfy
        for scarfy in scarfies: # In case the bullet hit more than one at a time
            bullet.kills += 1
            if bullets.kills >= 2:
                # Maybe remove bullet from bullets...
                bullet.kill()
                break
```

Or, having seen your comment, if you want your scarfy to require two hits before it's killed, do the same with an attribute `hits` on Scarfy and reversed logic in the code:

```
for scarfy, bullets in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.scarfys, self.bullets, False, True).items():
    if bullets:
        # The scarfy was hit by bullets
        for bullet in bullets: # In case the scarfy was hit by more than one bullet at a time
            scarfy.hits += 1
            if scarfy.hits >= 2:
                # Maybe remove scarfy from your list of scarfies
                scarfy.kill()
                break
```